# SecCertificateCopyData return optional Data?

Tags: ios, security, certificate

The documentation states:
Return Value: The DER representation of the certificate. Returns nil if the data passed in the certificate parameter is not a valid certificate object.

But function signature

```
func SecCertificateCopyData(_ certificate: SecCertificate) -> CFData
```

where is truth?

I am currently using forced optional

```
let data:CFData? = SecCertificateCopyData(cert);
guard let certificateData = data else{
    throw Error.invalidX509cert;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a typo in Swift documentation, because for Objective-C the return data type is `CFDataRef`, which can be toll-free bridged to `NSData*` type (pointer to `NSData`, which can be nil)